# Voice notes in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I work in field service, so I have to "journal" my time.  I would like to be able to record voice notes through out the day, and have them be transcribed to text, and archived by time and date.  It would be convenient to be able to look at Google calendar, a see the notes I have, for each day of the month, so I can go back and document my days.

I don't need to be able to see entire notes or journal entries on each day, but I would like to just see a time stamp of each entry.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Probably not doable in Google Calendar. I suggest looking into Evernote.

Comment: If you've an Android phone, the "Note to Self" feature will let you send/save to several different apps. I don't think Google Calendar is one, though. Google Keep is, though.